# Error:(19, 35) TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'. Why I can't extend interface in TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I want to extend an interface for React props. But I get TS error **Error:(19, 35) TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.**

1) Why error? `<T>` is generic type. It can't be declared before usage.

2) Why TS throws error in my code but doesn't throw for [DefinitelyTyped React types definitions here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts). Generic types `<T>` and many others are used everywhere in their code. Why they do not throw?

3) How to extend it the right way?

Here is my code.

I import **interface Props** from [DefinitelyTyped for React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1226):

```js
import React, {Props, PureComponent} from 'react';

// TS throws Error:(20, 27) TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
interface IHomeProps extends Props<T> { }

class Home extends PureComponent<IHomeProps> {
  render() {
    ...
  }
}

// interface Props definition
    interface Props<T> {
        children?: ReactNode;
        key?: Key;
        ref?: LegacyRef<T>;
    }
```

Comment: There is no `T` in scope. `IHomeProps` isn't generic and their is no enclosing scope declaring `T`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad There is no *enclosing scope declaring T* in React definitions either. Look at the code! Wy error here and not there then? You able to answer?

Answer (score 13):

You either need to specify a concrete `T` or declare a generic type parameter on the interface you are defining.

In react definitions the code works because they do define `T` the `<T>` after the interface is the definition for `T`, so it can then be used inside the interface. When you define your own interface, you need to define your own type parameter `T` and then forward if to `Props`. This is what a version that defined `T` would look like:

```
interface IHomeProps<T> extends Props<T> { }
                 //  ^ T is defined   ^ T is used
```

You probably want to just give a concrete type for `T`:

```
interface IHomeProps extends Props<HTMLDivElement> { }

class Home extends PureComponent<IHomeProps> {
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this look like with React hooks and functional components?

Answer (score 0):

Simple function example. Just extend the ObjectLiteral type.

Before:

```
private filterNull(data: Array<any>) {
    return data.filter(x => !!x);
}
```

After:

```
private filterNull<T extends ObjectLiteral>(data: Array<T>): Array<T> {
    return data.filter(x => !!x);
}
```